# Failed to load. Failed to recognize the file

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, developer-console

When I upload the apk file to Google Play error appears: "Failed to load. Failed to recognize the file." [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTqTT.png)

After checking in the console

```
 jarsigner -verify -verbose app-release.apk
```

it show:

> jar verified.
>
> Warning: This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated. This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate t his jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2026-02-21) or after any future revocation date.
>
> Re-run with the -verbose and -certs options for more details.

So, am I doing wrong?

Comment: On the issue of the certificate understood, other apk file signed by him has been successfully adopted in the Developer Console. So the problem remained for himself APK file this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break code and turning a few places the application has been accepted Developer Console. The problem was due to the use of vector application icons, although gradle created png copies. I copied the generated image files to catalog mipmap-***dpi.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have done anything wrong here. Try re-downloading the `.apk` and repeat what you've done above. If you are trying to disassemble the `.apk` to edit or get the source code I highly recommend using `apktool` instead

Comment: maybe I'm wrong to describe the problem. I created the app and going to post it in Google Play, but get an error.

Comment: Try resigning the `apk` with a new certificate and see if that works

Comment: Now I decided to start the application at first, gradually adding functionality that-be to understand which is why it was not taken. so for now, it has happened to sign and place my truncated application for the alpha test.